# jquery load function ignoring dynamic changes

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery's `load` function on a page to get the contents of a webpage and then print it. Here is my code:

```
$('#container').load('<?php print $_GET['load']; ?>', function(data) {

    window.print();
});
```

where the variable 'load' is the url.

The problem is that the page being loaded has a javascript designed filter attached it, meaning, on that page the user can click buttons to remove or display certain information e.g. `{ display: none }`.

However the items which are hidden by the user DO show up in this new page. I understand why this is so, the JavaScript isn't changing the base HTML of the page and it's still there, but I would like to find a way around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So when #container is refreshed with the new content, all of the old DOM elements (the internal version of your HTML) is destroyed and replaced - hence it looses the display: none properties.

One way around this would be to do something like this:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class="a">Stuff 1</div>
  <div class="b">Stuff 2</div>
  <div class="c">Stuff 3</div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="hide_something" data-hide-class="a" value="Hide A">
<input type="button" class="hide_something" data-hide-class="b" value="Hide B">
<input type="button" class="hide_something" data-hide-class="c" value="Hide C">

$('.hide_something').on("click", function() { 
  $('#container').addClass('hide_' + $(this).data("hide-class")); 
}​);


.hide_a .a,
.hide_b .b,
.hide_c .c { display: none; }
```

​Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qkjn/

So basically, when a user clicks a button, it adds a class to the outside container which CSS causes to hide the internal content.. Replacing the internal content won't change the CSS rules..

Another approach would be to store states in JS and then refresh them when the DOM reloads..

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I getting the content of #container via an ajax call (jquery load), so I don't have any of the filter information available.

Comment: I understood your question to be you're loading data from AJAX and repopulating a container which already has user data that is hidden..